# останавливать telebot для выпоплнения сторонней функции

Tags: python, telebot, telethon

Есть вот такой код:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('loading data...')
    all_messages()

    while True:
        try:
            print('bot is running...')
            bot.polling(non_stop=True)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            sleep(15)
```

Нужно раз в час останавливать `bot.polling` и перезапускать после выполнения `all_messages()`

Проблема в том, что `all_messages()` использует библиотеку telehon для получения информации с группе, которую не может получить telebot
Если запускать ее в процессе выполнения `bot.polling`, то вылетает ошибка связанная с потоками.

Вопрос, как останавливать `bot.polling` и перезапускать после выполнения `all_messages()`?

Comment: Во-первых, нет такой опции `non_stop`. Во-вторых, чем вам не подошёл `threading` или `multiprocessing`?